# Error al convertir el tipo de datos varchar a datetime?

Tags: sql

Hola tengo este procedimiento almacenado y al intentar ejecutarlo me da este error: `Error al convertir el tipo de datos varchar a datetime.`

Lo ejecuto de la siguiente manera:

```
EXEC [dbo].[SP_NI_Perfiles_UsuariosXPerfil_I] 'aarjona', 1, '04/18/2019 
12:00 PM', '05/04/2019 12:00 PM'
```

**PROCEDIMIENTO ALMACENADO**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_NI_Perfiles_UsuariosXPerfil_I]
   @Id_Usuario nvarchar(12) ,
   @Id_Perfil INT,
   @finicio DATETIME,
   @ftermino DATETIME 
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON

 IF (NOT EXISTS(
           SELECT *
             FROM NI_Perfiles_UsuariosXPerfil
             WHERE idUsuario = @Id_Usuario) )     
BEGIN 

INSERT INTO [dbo].[NI_Perfiles_UsuariosXPerfil]([idUsuario], [idperfil],
 [fInicio], [fTermino])
        VALUES (@Id_Usuario, @Id_Perfil, CONVERT (DATETIME, ISNULL(@finicio,
         GETDATE()), 103), CONVERT (DATETIME, ISNULL(@ftermino, GETDATE()),
          103));
END

ELSE 

BEGIN 
  UPDATE [dbo].[NI_Perfiles_UsuariosXPerfil]
     SET idUsuario = @Id_Usuario,
         idperfil = @Id_Perfil,
         fInicio = CONVERT (DATETIME, ISNULL(@finicio, GETDATE()), 103),
         fTermino = CONVERT (DATETIME, ISNULL(@ftermino, GETDATE()), 103)
     WHERE idUsuario = @Id_Usuario; 
END
 IF @@ERROR <> 0
  BEGIN
   SELECT 0 AS [ERROR];
  END
ELSE
  BEGIN
    SELECT scope_identity() AS [ID];
 END
```

He probado con diferentes maneras, pero la conversión de fechas no se me realiza en el procedimiento.

Comment: Daniela, deberías usar un formato No ambiguo como el ISO, por ejemplo: `'2019/04/18 12:00 PM'`.

Comment: ¿Cuál es la estructura de tu tabla? ¿Por qué utilizas `convert` en el update?